# Do multiple Django templates serve faster than a single template with if, elif blocks

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django projects, what's the best way to manage mutliple templates with similar content (in terms of server efficiency and user experience).

For example, for one project I'm doing, I have around 100 failure or success messages. I've parked all of them into a single template, separated by `{% if %}` and `{% elif %}` blocks. It's ~50KB in size.

A second approach I could have taken would be to have a separate template for each message.

Which method would be faster to load from the server (given all else equal)? I'm hazy about how Django templates are processed, hence asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a solution for you (it doesn't address your question directly, I'm afraid *), but can you use a dictionary and a key?  You'll have to build a filter in your views.

Here's what I use (that I think I got from stackoverflow):

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

<sup>* I'm answering with a 'bad' answer in the hopes this attracts more attention.  I'd like to know more about Django's performance.  Sadly, their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/performance/) only helps me so much.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for shining some light on this question.